# what's the equivalent of shouldStartLoadWithRequest in SFSafariViewController?

Tags: wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

is there a way to hook into SFSafariViewController
url loading ?

similar to in UIWebViewDelegate protocol:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:
```

That OR get autofill for usernames/passwords to work
in WKWebView

thanks

Comment: hey buddy, did you find any solution?

Comment: I doubt SFSafariViewController would get any api like that given that it's executed in a sandbox out of process. I think it'd be a major hardship (for apple) to do this (properly).